# Detect change in apps and user who made changes by a separate app Django.

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an app, say activitylogapp in the project that detects if in another app say Employeeapp some models are changed/updated and keep a log. I don't want touch Employeeapp. I can access changes by using signals in the models.py of activitylodapp. By this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from anotherapp.models import Employee
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Employee)
def save_handler(sender, instance, created, **kswargs):
    "Things I want to do"
```

The problem is I also want to access which user made these changes, like request.user.username that is used in views.py. 
Is it possible without explicitly injecting request object from view to activitylog app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a primitive [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#middleware-order-and-layering) into your "activitylogapp" with `process_request` to store the `request`.

As for storing the `request`, I see 2 options:

1. Ugly but fast to implement. Save the `request` globally. It shouldn't affect anything as you get a fresh new cloned thread for each request, which dies right after the request has been processed.
2. More sophisticated, without globals. Utilize the fact, that Django signals create [weak references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference) to their receiver functions. So you can attach `save_handler` to the `request` itself, and they will get [GC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))-ed together in the end. Something like that:

   ```
   class MyMiddleware(object):

       def process_request(request):

           def save_handler(sender, instance, created, **kswargs):
               user = request.user
               "do the stuff you want to do"

           # without the following line, the save_handler will be
           # garbage collected right away since nothing references it
           request._my_save_handler_instance = save_handler 

           post_save.register(save_handler, ...)
   ```